# Decrypting password encrypted private key in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I've exported an AWS certificate using the methods described in this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/sdk-export.html

But I want to decrypt the password encrypted private key in order to use it in my program. I wrote the following code to do that:

```
String private_key = "<encrypted private key of the form -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----->"
String passwd = "password used to export the key"

       try{
            EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(private_key.getBytes());

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwd.toCharArray());
            SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());
            Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);
            KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But this code throws:
**java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor**

Any suggestions what I'm missing here?

Comment: It's bad enough that we don't' get a private (test) key to go on, but could you please at least print out the strings you are using to parameterize the crypto object instances? As it is it is simply impossible to debug unless you know the (horribly described, and with terrible example code) AWS SDK. I mean, really Amazon, who did you hire to write that code?

Comment: _If_ that PKCS8 uses an old-style i.e. single-OID scheme (not PBES2), which I don't know and the AWS page doesn't say, you need to de-PEM it before feeding to `EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo`: remove the header/trailer lines entirely, and de-base64 the rest either removing or ignoring the linebreaks; `java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder()` does the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public PrivateKey readPrivateKey(String privateKeyContent, String passPhrase){

  PrivateKey privateKey = null;

  try {
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(privateKeyContent));

    byte[] content = pemReader.readPemObject().getContent();

    EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptPKInfo = new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(content);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());

    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray());

    SecretKeyFactory secFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(encryptPKInfo.getAlgName());

    Key pbeKey = secFac.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

    AlgorithmParameters algParams = encryptPKInfo.getAlgParameters();

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, algParams);

    KeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = encryptPKInfo.getKeySpec(cipher);

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

  } catch (Exception e) {}

  return privateKey;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use BouncyCastle, use `PEMParser` then `JcaPEMKeyConverter` with the result of `JcePKCSPBEInputDecryptorProviderBuilder`; that's much simpler _and_ handles now-more-common PBES2 as well as traditional single-OID schemes.